# Ping DBLink if DB_LINK, USERNAME and the HOST is available

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

How to ping DB link if I only have **DB_LINK, USERNAME and the HOST**? Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by 'ping'? See if the link is valid and the remote DB available from within your local DB? Or are you trying to do something from outside the database?

Comment: I just want to check if the DBLink is active and healthy as a monthly health check.

Answer (score 1):

You can see if a link is valid and available just by issuing a query across it; I'd generally use a simple:

```
select * from dual@db_link
```

since the remote `dual` table should always be visible to all users. If that gets a row back then all is well. Otherwise you'll get an error you can investigate.

Since you refer to columns from the `all_db_links` view, you could do a simple test of all the links that lists with something like:

```
set serveroutput on
-- or equivalent for your client

declare
  l_dummy dual.dummy%type;
begin
  for r in (select db_link from all_db_links) loop
    begin
      execute immediate 'select dummy from dual@' || r.db_link into l_dummy;
      dbms_output.put_line('Link ' || r.db_link || ' is OK.');
      -- release undo locks and link 
      rollback work;
      execute immediate 'alter session close database link ' || r.db_link;
    exception
      when others then
        dbms_output.put_line('Link ' || r.db_link || ' is not OK: ' || sqlerrm);
    end;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

I wouldn't normally advocate trapping `when others` but in this case it's useful. From that you might see output like:

```
Link MY_LINK_1 is not OK: ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred
Link MY_LINK_2 is OK.
Link MY_LINK_3 is not OK: ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
Link MY_LINK_4 is OK.
```

etc.

Comment: where should I run this query "select * from dual@db_link"?

Comment: @JCBA - from any client. You've tagged the question with SQL\*Plus and SQL Developer, you can run either that query or the PL/SQL block from either of those. The `db_link` in that query has to be replaced with your actual link name of course, i.e. a value from the `db_link` column in `all_db_links` - as the PL/SQL version is doing via the cursor loop.

Comment: I ran the query to one of our specific DB in the sqlDev and it gives me an error "ORA-02019: connection description for remote database not found
02019. 00000 -  "connection description for remote database not found".

Comment: I can't see what is in your `all_db_links` view or what actual query you ran. Maybe you have quoted identifiers?

Comment: I ran the "select * from dual@our_db_link_name" without quote and it gives me the above error. By the way the dblinks that i'm testing is private.

Comment: If your user can see `our_db_link_name` listed in `all_db_links` then that should. work. The error implies that they can't. Or maybe that they need to add a domain, if the environment is different, but that seems unlikely. Are you testing from the same account that usually uses the link?

Comment: dual@db_link query was running and it output a row.

Comment: I tried your second query, the second one from which it will loop to all available db_link in that database. some links is OK but some gives an error "Link link_name is not OK: ORA-02020: too many database links in use"

Comment: @JCBA - right, I didn't have enough to hit that. I've added steps to free links after testing.